# Migrating a Supabase database to another project

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, supabase

I am attempting to migrate database within Supabase to another project, for example i want to migrate to another project while keeping the data intact in the current project so my site can run normally, new database will have some changes in the structure where it will be more organized, after testing then it will replace prod. How can I achieve that?

problem is that I'm lost between the commands and how will the process look like.

Comment: There is documentation for this here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/platform/migrating-and-upgrading-projects#migrate-your-project